# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\joblister-laravel-8-main\resources\views\job-application\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a job portal and I am getting the following error when I want to display the job applicants to a company. I am not able to figure out where the error is, please help me!

Laravel is showing:
[This is the error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEwtY.png)

The code of my index.blade.php for this is:

```
@extends('layouts.account')

@section('content')
  <div class="account-layout  border">
    <div class="account-hdr bg-primary text-white border">
      Job Applications
    </div>
    <div class="account-bdy p-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <p class="mb-3 alert alert-primary">Listing all the Applicants who applied for your <strong>job listings</strong>.</p>
          <div class="table-responsive pt-3">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped small">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Applicant Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Job Title</th>
                  <th>Applied on</th>
                  <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @if($applications->count())
                  @foreach($applications as $application)
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>{{$application->user->name}}</td>
                    <td><a href="mailto:{{$application->user->email}}">{{$application->user->email}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('post.show',['job'=>$application->post->id])}}">{{substr($application->post->job_title,0,14)}}...</a></td>
                    <td>{{$application->created_at}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('jobApplication.show',['id'=>$application])}}" class="btn primary-outline-btn">View</a>
                      <form action="{{route('jobApplication.destroy')}}" method="POST" class="d-inline-block">
                        @csrf
                        @method('delete')
                        <input type="hidden" name="application_id" value="{{$application->id}}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn danger-btn">Delete</button>
                      </form>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                @else
                  <tr>
                    <td>You haven't received any job applications.</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                @endif
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4 custom-pagination">
            {{ $applications && $applications->links() }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endSection
```

Comment: So what is `$application->user`, since it's not an object? Does `$application->user` exist?

Comment: You're looping over `$applications`, but if any `$application` doesn't have an associated `->user`, or `->user` doesn't return an Object, your code will fail. A simple `if ($application->user)` before trying to call `$application->user->name` (or `->email`) is all you need. There are other methods too, like adding `->has('user')` to your `JobApplication` query, or `$application->user?->name` if on PHP8, etc. But, this error is entirely on you; you told the code to try to access that, but it's not there; you need to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the join relation with the Application and User table and the records are in $applications variable, Its clearly mentioned in error that the user doesn't exist. We can just tell from this piece of code what's wrong. Can you show us the controller thats passing the $applications value ? The possible solution could be $application->user['name'];

Comment: `class JobApplicationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $applicationsWithPostAndUser = null;
        $company = auth()->user()->company;

        if ($company) {
            $ids =  $company->posts()->pluck('id');
            $applications = JobApplication::whereIn('post_id', $ids);
            $applicationsWithPostAndUser = $applications->with('user', 'post')->latest()->paginate(10);
        }
        return view('job-application.index')->with([
            'applications' => $applicationsWithPostAndUser,
        ]);
    }`

Comment: Did you try ` $application->user['name'] ` instead of ` $application->user->name;